# WPF - How to get rid of false design time errors

Tags: wpf

In design time I have a couple of false errors that seems to be caused by WPF not being able to estimate the value of things without actually running them. This of course works flawlessly in run time.
The question is how do I get rid of these errors?

Here is one example:

I have in a class the following two:

```
public static bool IsHubb {get; set;} 
public static bool IsEC { get { return !IsHubb; } }
```

The following convertor works perfectly well:

```
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (HubbCostOfferPage.IsHubb && HubbCostOfferPage.CarObj.TestApprovedDate == null)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

The following however (although very similar) gives an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error, which means the only thing I can see on design time without commenting out the StaticResource definition is a big error:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (HubbCostOfferPage.IsEC == true && HubbCostOfferPage.CarObj.TestApprovedDate == null)
        return Visibility.Visible;
    else
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

If I replace HubbCostOfferPage.IsEC with HubbCostOfferPage.IsHubb, all works fine so I know that there is where the problem is.

If I replace HubbCostOfferPage.IsEC with !HubbCostOfferPage.IsHubb in the convertor, I get the same problem. The designer seems to complain because it can't evaluate "!" during design time.

Any ideas how to make this work in design time as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Pauls Answer I would suggest not to check is `CarObj` is null, because during runtime the exception shall be thrown.

I suggest to change your converter as follows:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,  
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)  
{  
  if (ApplicationIsInDesignMode) { return Visibility.**WHATEVER YOU LIKE ***; }
  if (HubbCostOfferPage.IsEC == true && HubbCostOfferPage.CarObj.TestApprovedDate == null)
    return Visibility.Visible;
else
    return Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private static bool ApplicationIsInDesignMode
    {
        get { return (bool)(DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(DependencyObject)).DefaultValue); }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `during runtime the exception shall be thrown`? I'm curious why you think a check for null will result in an exception during runtime.

Comment: @Paul: During design time some objects might be null, because a Factory or something is not called, so the property is null. I think this is okay. But during runtime, the property shall not be null. So I believe it's not Converter who is responsible for checking this. But of course there might be some circumstances where an object can be null and the converter shall not throw an exception.

Comment: The great thing about your solution is that it can be used to solve other problems as well. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Turn the designer off - it's more trouble than it's worth. Associate .xaml files with the code editor (right-click, open with, then set as default) and you'll get a faster experience and still have Intellisense. You can use Blend as and when you need it.

Comment: It doesn't exactly answer the question but it's the best advice for the situation in general

Comment: I prefer this: Tools / Options / Text Editor / XAML / Miscellaneous -> "Always open documents in full XAML view" checked

Comment: @Kent not yet, since i am perfectly satisfied with the full XAML view, but seeing you rather enthusiastic about it, i will give it a try the next time im on a WPF project

Comment: @Kent: Thank for your answer. If I didn't use the designer I wouldn't have this problem at all since it is only the designer that shows an error, så as long as i ignore it i don't have a problem. I.e. - this does not help.

Comment: @UrbanEsc: Thanks for your answer. It was exactly the kind of solution I was looking for, something in the setting. Unfortunately I tried your solution and it didn't seem to have any affect on the error massage. :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
public object Convert(/*snipped*/)
{
#if DEBUG
    if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName == "devenv")
        return Visibility.Visible;
#endif
    if (HubbCostOfferPage.IsEC == true && HubbCostOfferPage.CarObj.TestApprovedDate == null)
        return Visibility.Visible;
    else
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Edit: At second glance, the designer is likely complaining because HubbCostOfferPage.CarObj is null. You could probably also fix this by changing the code to:

```
public object Convert(/*snipped*/)
{
    if (HubbCostOfferPage.IsEC && 
        HubbCostOfferPage.CarObj != null &&
        HubbCostOfferPage.CarObj.TestApprovedDate == null)
        return Visibility.Visible;
    else
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Which would have a side effect of being better production code too.

2nd Edit in response to your comment, since this will require code:

> As I wrote, replacing the IsEC with the IsHubb solves the problem and putting an ! before IsEC causes it, so it is absolutely not the CarObj that is the problem.

On startup, `IsHubb` is initialized to false. C# short-circuits boolean logic, so in the following:

```
if (HubbCostOfferPage.IsHubb && ...
```

Everything after the logical And is *NOT* being evaluated. When you changed the code to:

```
if (HubbCostOfferPage.IsEC == true && ...
```

Everything after `&&` is now being evaluated. Integral types such as `bool` are not going to be targets of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", and obviously `HubbCostOfferPage` is not null, so the likely culprit is CarObj. Without seeing your code, this was merely a suggested idea.

As to the second part of your question, the DEBUG directives just compile out the code that does the designer check when you compile in release mode. You can remove them if you are doing any design time editing in release mode. The part you need is everything in-between.

Comment: As I wrote, replacing the IsEC with the IsHubb solves the problem and putting an ! before IsEC causes it, so it is absolutely not the CarObj that is the problem. Therefore the second solution won't help.
As for your first solution - I am not sure if I get it right: If I am working on the project and compiling with Debug, won't that mean that Debug is the section that will be executed? In that case, it doesn't solve the problem as it will behave wrong when running the application while working on it.

Comment: I edited my answer to answer more comprehensively, but either bit of code should work for you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. All you say makes a lot of sense, which is exactly why this problem puzzle me so much.
I have taken out the ObjCar totally from the converter, just to check if there is any chance that you are right about it but sadly - you are wrong. This has nothing to do with the CarObj: the error staid the same even when there CarObj is not even mentioned in the converter but disappear as soon as the IsEC is away. Which is very strange since you are right about it not even being able to be null.

Comment: As for your answer about the DEBUG, it is exactly as I suspected. Which means that if I use that solution I would end up having problems while developing (= compiling in DEBUG) that don't even exist in Release mode. Not a good idea.

Comment: So if you change the block to `if (HubbCostOfferPage.IsEC)`, dropping the second check, you still get the error?

Comment: Did you try adding the DEBUG directive? The code I posted **only** affects the designer. When you actually run the application, it will behave the same in Debug or Release.